# Antonym synonym

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

[antonym](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/antonym) and [opposite-word](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opposite-word) are suggesting the same thing. They should be merged.

Comment: What happens when the tags are merged? Would one be able to find **antonym**  by typing in **opposite** for a tag? At the moment, it looks like **antonym** can not be found when typing in **opposite** for tags.  It might be useful if that was possible.